pushToStartTokenUpdates updates no data without creating an Activity
I'm trying to build a live activity widget on my iOS app.
There are 2 kind of tokens used in live activities:

pushToken (used to update live activity with push notifications.)
pushToStartToken (used to start live activity with push notifications.)

I can get both pushToken and pushToStartToken after creating an activity. But I just want to get pushToStartToken without starting an actual activity.
This is the code that I can get the pushToStartToken:
private func startNewLiveActivity() async {
    guard #available(iOS 16.2, *) else { return }
    
    let attributes = MyWidgetAttributes(
        homeTeam: "Badger",
        awayTeam: "Lion",
        date: "12/09/2023"
    )
    
    let initialContentState = ActivityContent(
        state: MyWidgetAttributes.ContentState(
            homeTeamScore: 0,
            awayTeamScore: 0,
            lastEvent: "Match Start"
        ),
        staleDate: nil
    )
    
    guard let activity = try? Activity.request(
        attributes: attributes,
        content: initialContentState,
        pushType: .token
    ) else { return }
    
    if #available(iOS 17.2, *) {
        Task {
            for await data in Activity< MyWidgetAttributes>.pushToStartTokenUpdates {
                let token = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
                // THE DESIRED TOKEN IS GENERATED HERE
            }
        }
    }
    
    for await data in activity.pushTokenUpdates {
        let token = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
        // I send token to server here.
    }
}

But I don't want to create an activity to just get the pushToStartToken, that's why I separated it into another function like this:
private func getPushToStartToken() async {
    guard #available(iOS 17.2, *) else { return }
    
    Task {
        for await data in Activity<MyWidgetAttributes>.pushToStartTokenUpdates {
            let token = data.map { String(format: "%02x", $0) }.joined()
            // THIS DOESN'T GENERATE ANY TOKENS SINCE THE ACTIVITY IS NOT CREATED
        }
    }
}

But it doesn't update any tokens.
There is a discussion about this issue on Apple Developer Forums.
If anyone have any idea on this issue, thank you in advance.

Have you tried executing the function in AppDelegate? I was also experiencing issues with getting new start tokens and had to move the code to AppDelegate method application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:).
However, it as mentioned in the Apple Developer forums, the token is not created every time you launch the app.
The easiest way to make sure the token should be generated is by erasing all content in Simulator (Device -> Erase all content and settings...). Clean installation should always generate new token.
